# How to query rows in SQLite and find the lowest value?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a newbie android developer and I am trying to design a simple app based on the notepad tutorial from the android developer website. So far I can create and delete rows. Each row consists of a Name and Number. What I want to do to organise the rows in relation to their value. So whatever row has the lowest number will appear at the top, and then the row with the second lowest number will appear second etc.

My question is how do I calculate which row has the lowest number? When a user creates a row with a Name and a Number, where is this information stored in my program?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
                     new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY},
                     null, null, null, null,
                     KEY_TITLE);
 }
```

without the "DESC" clause.

Answer (score 2):

Why not put a `ORDER BY Number` onto your query when you want to find the row with lowest value?

Comment: I assume you mean `ORDER BY`, not `SORT BY`.

Comment: Yes! i updated the post to reflect this. It is early in the morning and brainfarts can happen often at this time.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. Here is my code:  public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, KEY_TITLE + " DESC");
    }